# How to put image in Community Login page

Tags: community

I have created a Salesforce Community . How can I put an image in the Login Page of my community ? Is that possibile

> **NOTE**

I do not want to add a header image, but rather an image in the main content on the right side of the page

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer in this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CuHw9ZAq3I)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible ..

```
>   go to setup --> communities-->click on manage communities --> click
> on edit -> there you see a popup window -->click on login button -->
> then choose header logo ..
```

note..you need to upload to image in document and it should be in public .

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is simple .

> Go to communities and click on edit.Next go to pop up screen and click on login and assign to header the image you like

[image]

[image]

> Update

I dont think its possible to add the image through any configuration outofbox.An alternative could be built a site page and then associate the login logic for the community.

Comment: This is to add header right. I just want to put an image in the right side of my login page .Just like the images in the Salesforce login pages. Not the header . Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @User Updated the answer .I dont think we can change that outofbox .We need to write a vf and then use login class provided by salesforce to login